# lining up background image that is a fixed attachment among a grid of similar divs and images

Tags: css, background, background-image, fixed, parallax

The Fiddle isnt rendering the exact grid properly but it gives you an idea of what I'm going for. Each div has a fixed background image. The problem is each background image is defaulting to the top left corner, even after trying to reposition the image using background-position.

https://jsfiddle.net/hLu7gvo3/

The styling looks like this

```
#thumb1{
 background-size: cover;    
 background-position: center;
 background: url("../img/gal1.png");
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.gallerythumb {
 color: white;
 position: static;
 float: left;
 width: 33.333vw;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

and the html as you'd imagine

```
<div class="gallerythumb" id="thumb2">1</div>
```

I tried setting the sizing property as container but that didn't do much. Anyone have any clue how to center the background image within the div?

Comment: Could you elaborate . You want each respective image to be centered for ** id="thumb * " ** div.

Comment: @govind If I'm reading your comment correctly yes. Each background image will be centered within the div it is fixed inside of.